# find files with ? in filename and rename these

Tags: find, rename, xargs

After wget a Wordpress I have files with a "?" in filename.

How can I rename these and remove the end of filename?

```
find -type f -name '*.js*' | xargs
./PATH/TO/xxx.js?ver=1.0.0

find -type f -name '*.js*' | xargs rename "s/\?.*$//g"
```

Not working!

```
find -type f -name '*.js*' | xargs rename -n "s/xxx/123/g"
```

No output!

Part of source code:

```
...
        <script src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/example/js/example.js?ver=1.0.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us how the files received after `wget` are looking like?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an easy solution:

```
find | rename 's/\?ver=1\.0\.0$//g'
```

A more general way:

```
find | rename 's/\?ver=\d\.\d\.\d$//g'
```

DO NOT FORGET TO TEST!

```
find | rename -n ...
```

Keep it simple, stupid. :-)